# How to effectively delete a lot of mnesia tables

Tags: erlang, mnesia

I faced a situation when I need to delete a lot of mnesia tables on the node (about 20000). Since there is a name pattern for these tables I can collect and delete them this way:

```
Tables = [Table || Table <- mnesia:system_info(tables), re:run(atom_to_list(Table), "<pattern>") /= nomatch],
lists:foreach(
    fun (Table) ->
        mnesia:delete_table(Table)
    end,
    Tables).
```

However deleting them one by one is very slow and it takes very long to delete 20k tables.
Is there any way to do it more effectively?

Answer (score 1):

you can spawn processes.

```
lists:foreach(
    fun (Table) ->
        spawn(mnesia, delete_table, [Table])
    end,
    Tables).
```

Comment: It only scales the above solution, but it doesn't provide any improvement.